# A logic question on two binary variables

Tags: logic

I recently purchased some nightlights with sensors. The sensor will make sure the nightlight will only be tuned on in a dark environment. Let's assume the sensor is binary, ON or OFF.

Here is the question come to my mind, what will happen if we put 2 night lights in one dark room that they can trigger each other's sensor?

It can not be both OFF, and cannot be both ON. If one ON and one OFF, which one should be ON?

Then, how about I put a mirror on one nightlight, that its light on its sensor? Should it be ON or OFF? Both seems to be wrong.

Is this a math question or logic question or physics question? I am new to the community, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Physically speaking, you should check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7dV1PNPxAk) (around 1:10) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is wrong because the light sensor **does not** make the light on **whenever** the room is dark, but instead there is a slight **delay**. So what you will get in the second case is that it will oscillate between on and off (until it burns out from excessive switching). In the first case, which one ends up being on depends on the tiny technical details of the circuitry as well as how exactly it runs. It is **theoretically** true that if both circuits are identical and have exactly the same behaviour and are activated at exactly the same time in symmetric locations in a perfectly symmetrical room then they will switch on at exactly the same time, and then off at the same time after a while, and then on again, in perfect synchrony. But **in the real world** that never happens; due to slight deviation from perfect symmetry eventually they will go out of sync, at which point the one that is still on will remain on and the one that is off will remain off, and the result is a stable state. The oscillatory state is called a meta-stable state, since it is stable for a significant duration but will eventually 'decay' to a stable state.